# How to link netcdf as shared libraries during conda installation of esmpy?

Tags: python, python-xarray

I installed [`esmpy`](https:///https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/esmpy) using `conda install -c conda-forge esmpy` but am unable to get it to create a mesh from an existing Netcdf file using something like [this](https://earthsystemmodeling.org/esmpy_doc/release/latest/html/examples.html):

```
mesh = ESMF.Mesh(filename=myfile.nc),filetype=ESMF.FileFormat.ESMFMESH)
```

My input file is the output from the CAM-SE global atmospheric model at `ne120` resolution. This model returns unstructured output. I get an error message saying that Netcdf should be built as a shared library. I know the Netcdf libraries exist because I use `xarray` all the time to read and process them. But how does one link those libraries during the installation step for `esmpy` using `conda`? Do I need to build `esmpy` from source to be able to do this?

**Update**: Have added the full traceback below. I installed netcdf using conda-forge within the conda environment I was using and it appears that was not the source of the error as the error message remains unchanged. I am now wondering if my command for generating `mesh` is just going to work after directly feeding in a CAM-SE output file. The file does not really have any information about the number of elements, etc. Also, should I rename the dimensions to some common form expected by ESMF? How will ESMF know which dimension represents the number of nodes, etc.? Here is the list of dimensions from one of the output files (followed by the traceback):

```
dimensions:
        time = UNLIMITED ; // (292 currently)
        lev = 30 ;
        ilev = 31 ;
        ncol = 777602 ;
        nbnd = 2 ;
        chars = 8 ;
        string1 = 1 ;
```

----------Traceback------------------------

```
ArgumentError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <cell line: 5>()
----> 5 grid = ESMF.Mesh(filename='B1850.ne120_t12.cam.h2.0338-01-01-21600.nc', 
filetype=ESMF.FileFormat.ESMFMESH)

File /software/conda/envs/dask_Jul23_2022/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ESMF/util/decorators.py:81, in initialize.<locals>.new_func(*args, **kwargs)
     78 from ESMF.api import esmpymanager
     80 esmp = esmpymanager.Manager(debug = False)
---> 81 return func(*args, **kwargs)

File /software/conda/envs/dask_Jul23_2022/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ESMF/api/mesh.py:198, in Mesh.__init__(self, parametric_dim, spatial_dim, coord_sys, filename, filetype, convert_to_dual, add_user_area, meshname, mask_flag, varname)
    195     self._coord_sys = coord_sys
    196 else:
    197     # call into ctypes layer
--> 198     self._struct = ESMP_MeshCreateFromFile(filename, filetype,
    199                                           convert_to_dual, 
    200                                           add_user_area, meshname, 
    201                                           mask_flag, varname)
    202     # get the sizes
    203     self._size[node] = ESMP_MeshGetLocalNodeCount(self)

File /software/conda/envs/dask_Jul23_2022/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ESMF/util/decorators.py:93, in netcdf.<locals>.new_func(*args, **kwargs)
     90 from ESMF.api.constants import _ESMF_NETCDF
     92 if _ESMF_NETCDF:
---> 93     return func(*args, **kwargs)
     94 else:
     95     raise NetCDFMissing("This function requires ESMF to have been built with NetCDF.")

File /software/conda/envs/dask_Jul23_2022/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ESMF/interface/cbindings.py:1218, in ESMP_MeshCreateFromFile(filename, fileTypeFlag, convertToDual, addUserArea, meshname, maskFlag, varname)
   1197 """
   1198 Preconditions: ESMP has been initialized.\n
   1199 Postconditions: An ESMP_Mesh has been created.\n
   (...)
   1215     string (optional)  :: varname\n
   1216     """
   1217 lrc = ct.c_int(0)
-> 1218 mesh = _ESMF.ESMC_MeshCreateFromFile(filename, fileTypeFlag,
   1219                                      convertToDual, addUserArea,
   1220                                      meshname, maskFlag, varname,
   1221                                      ct.byref(lrc))
   1222 rc = lrc.value
   1223 if rc != constants._ESMP_SUCCESS:

ArgumentError: argument 1: <class 'AttributeError'>: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

Comment: Did you also install netcdf using conda-forge? Try creating a new environment and installing everything you need with the same channel. And please always post the [full traceback](//realpython.com/python-traceback) when asking about errors, and more info about the commands you ran to build your environment when having installation issues. Good luck!

Comment: This question is now almost impossible to read. Please consider revising it so that a newcomer can follow it. Starting with updates is very confusing to anyone who hasn't read the question in the first place. Also, please try to make the problem reproducible. Given the error, it could be a number of things, including issues caused by updates to dependencies.

Comment: I have moved the 'Update' from the beginning to the end to make the post less confusing. At this stage, I am not sure how to reproduce this problem as I don't know what exactly I need to reproduce, given the errors are so cryptic (to me).  Will it help if I paste the output from `conda list`?